# how to make a recursive counter

Tags: c, recursion, counter

I'm trying to make a counter function that takes `n` as an argument
so if `n` is `2` the result would be `01, 02, 03, ..., 99`
and if `n` is `3` the result would be `001, 002, ..., 999` and so on
I'm new to recursion and couldn't find a way to do it so I decided to make a solution for `n = 2` then I'll try to generalize it
but unfortunately I couldn't.
My solution for `n = 2` is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void    allPossibleComb(void)
{
    char    counter[2];

    counter[0] = '0';
    counter[1] = '0';
    while (counter[0] <= '9')
    {
        counter[1] = '0';
        while (counter[1] <= '9')
        {
            printf("%c%c ", counter[0], counter[1]);
            counter[1]++;
        }
        counter[0]++;
    }
}

int main(void) {
  allPossibleComb();
  return 0;
}
```

So for `n = 2` I needed two while loops the conclusion I had if `n = 9` I'll need 9 while loops and that pushed to think of a recursive solution

I made a lot of attemps but I just couldn't get it so here the code of my last attempt which won't make any sense but I'll just put it here

```c
void recursive_counter(int n,int c, char seq[])
{
    
    if(seq[n] == '9'){
        seq[n] = 0;
        return;
    }

    while(seq[c] < '9')
    {
        seq[c]++;
        print_sequence(seq);
    }
    recursive_counter(n, c+1, seq);
}
```

`n` is length of array, `c` supposed to be an index and `seq` is an array ['0', '0'].

How can I approach such recursive problems?
Note: it's a task where I can't use for loops and I can't use integers

Comment: Is the `print_sequence()` function something you invented, or was it provided to you?

Comment: It is often useful to express in English (or other human language), as simply as possible, what a given function does in terms of its arguments.  Something like "Repeatedly increments the 'n'-digit counter stored in 'seq' and prints the result until the counter rolls over."  That specific description can't be right for your particular function, however, because it does not explain the role of the `c` argument.  I recommend formulating such descriptions *before* writing the function implementations -- that helps you stay on track to where you intended to go.

Comment: Recursion is really tricky for students, what worked well for me is to think of recursion as an induction. so you need to ask yourself the following questions, what the function does? you can say anything you want, for example, it returns an array with the solution regarding the given n(arr[0] = (n zeroes)1 and so on), you need to define it well. 
 what is the base?(what is the easiest n that you can solve this function), and what is the step of the induction, lets's say that every number lower than n if you call the function it returns this array, can you solve it for n?

Comment: @JohnBollinger oh yeah sorry, so that's a function that prints an array

Comment: continue the comment: and simply assume that it works for n-1, so you get arr[0] = (n-1 zeros) 1 and so on, now solve it for n, after you define these things, the recursion become easy and you need only code it

Comment: That does not answer the question I asked, @AzerSD.  Is it your invention?  I ask because if you invented it then it probably needs to receive the array size as an argument, but if it was provided to you then it may be reasonable to assume that it has special knowledge of the array size.

Comment: @JohnBollinger it is my invention here is the code https://gist.github.com/AzerSD/0c2875b9977515221966e3f13a93a2b3

Comment: @MosheLevy I think that helps thanks <3

Comment: If you can't use `for` loops then are you really allowed to use `while` loops?  Any `for` loop can be rewritten as a `while` loop, so excluding only `for` loops and allowing others is pretty pointless.

Comment: looking on some of the answers here, they simply make the recursion a for loop, thats recursion because they call the same function, but you do not really learn recursion like that. recursion is intented to solve problem by knowing to solve a sub problem, so recursion code usually easier to code and shorter if you define it right. and i usually define everything by words as a math proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this to use recusion, and the while loop is short enough and constant length so if you really wanted to you could get rid of it. You should be able to call `allPossibleComb(2)` and get the same output as your working function.

```
void recursive(unsigned int n, const char* str, unsigned int length)
{
    if (!n) {
        // if n == 0 we are passed the final layer and should print
        printf("%s ", str);
        return;
    }
    
    // buffer for print
    char buffer[21];
    // copy the input string so we don't change it
    strcpy(buffer, str);
    // add the next digit + null terminator
    buffer[length] = '0'-1;
    buffer[length+1] = '\0';
    do {
        // increment digit in current layer and recurse
        buffer[length]++;
        recursive(n - 1, buffer, length + 1);
    } while (buffer[length] != '9'); // continue looping until we have done all digits '0' to '9'
}
```

```
// call recursive without having to put in initial values for some of the arguments
void allPossibleComb(unsigned int n)
{
    recursive(n, "", 0);
}
```

`allPossibleComb` doesn't do anything here but call `recursive` for you with the starting values for `str` and `length`

Answer (score 1):

My two cents (without recursion):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void all_possible_comb (unsigned int digits) {

    if (digits == 0) return;

    /*  As we are dealing with a fixed-length string we use `fwrite()`
        instead of `printf()`; that allows to avoid adding a NUL
        terminator to `output_buffer`.  */

    char output_buffer[digits];
    unsigned int cursor = 0;

set_to_zero:
    memset(output_buffer + cursor, '0', digits - cursor);

print_number:
    fwrite(output_buffer, 1, digits, stdout);
    putchar('\n');
    cursor = digits;

next_digit:
    if (cursor < 1) return;
    if (output_buffer[--cursor] > '8') goto next_digit;
    output_buffer[cursor]++;
    if (++cursor < digits) goto set_to_zero;
    goto print_number;

}

int main (const int argc, const char * const * const argv) {

    all_possible_comb(3);
    return 0;

}
```

Or, alternatively, by using the heap and a completely different approach (still no recursion):

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void all_possible_comb (unsigned int digits) {

    char * format;

    if (asprintf(&format, "%%0%ulu\n", digits) == -1) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory\n");
        return;

    }

    long unsigned int limit = 1;

    for (
        unsigned int idx = 0;
            idx < digits;
        limit *= 10, idx++
    );

    for (
        long unsigned int count = 0;
            count < limit;
        printf(format, count++)
    );

    free(format);

}

int main (const int argc, const char * const * const argv) {

    all_possible_comb(2);
    return 0;

}
```

As you might have guessed, I hate recursive functions.

Answer (score 1):

Since some people already answered I will try to show you how to do it and how to think on the solution.

as I told you in the comment, the most important thing to do is to define exactly what your recursion function gets and what it does. that's the hardest part, you need to think on something that will work for you best, lets look on the following defintion:

function inputs:

num of digits - how many digits i want.

last number - what is the last number i want to print.

what it does? - print all the numbers until the last number with zeroes if needed to fit the num of digits.

on what we do the recursion? - on the last number

so after we have all the defintion, lets solve it as an induction.

base: last number = 1, can we solve it? sure, just print 1 with numbers of zeroes needed.

step: lets say we know how to solve it for last_num -1 can we solve it or last_num? sure, we first print comma, and then we just need to print the last num with the numbers of zeroes needed.(i truly assume that it worked for last_num-1, that's the catch)

if you got it until here, you just need to code it and understand how to code every step of the induction.

since you got already some solutions i will post my code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_num_digits(int num)
{
    int digits = 0;
    while(num != 0)
    {
        num = num/10;
        digits++;
    }
    return digits;
}

void print_with_zeroes(int digits, int num)
{
    int num_digits = get_num_digits(num);
    int num_zeroes = digits - num_digits;
    while(num_zeroes > 0)
    {
        printf("0");
        num_zeroes--;
    }
    printf("%d", num);
}

void rec(int digits, int last_num_to_print)
{
    if(last_num_to_print == 1)
    {
        print_with_zeroes(digits, last_num_to_print);
    }
    else
    {
        rec(digits, last_num_to_print - 1);
        printf(",");
        print_with_zeroes(digits, last_num_to_print);
    }
}

int main()
{
    rec(2, 99);//just call to the function with the right parameters

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generalized pure recursive solution, you can control the width by modifying the initial `c` in `main`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void counter_recursive(char c[], int idx, int n);
void digit_recursive(char c[], int idx, int n, int digit);

char nums[] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0' };

void digit_recursive(char c[], int idx, int n, int digit)
{
    if (digit >= sizeof(nums))
    {
        return;
    }

    counter_recursive(c, idx+1, n);
    c[idx] = nums[digit];
    digit_recursive(c, idx, n, digit+1); 
}

void counter_recursive(char c[], int idx, int n)
{
    if (idx >= n)
    {
        printf("%s ", c);
        return;
    }

    digit_recursive(c, idx, n, 0);
}

int main()
{
    char c[] = "000";
    counter_recursive(c, 0, sizeof(c)-1);
}
```

Note: it doesn't print commas and it prints zero at first.